# Is there any free tool for creating database (mysql preferred) tables from existing html forms automatically?

Tags: mysql, html, database, forms

I got a front-end designer to write tons of html form for me. Is there any free tool for creating database (mysql prefered) tables from existing html forms automatically? Names and datatypes of table fields would be generated based on names and types of form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be quite difficult with traditional relational databases like MySQL, where you would have to define a schema for your database before being in a position to insert and manipulate data. The schema has to define all the column names, as well as their datatypes.

All this is very difficult to auto-generate from an HTML form.